# Virtual environment discovery Via vCenter in pYvmomi

Tags: python, vmware

I need a pYvmomi script which will provide the following information:

1. Get all VM’s from vCenter
2. Get the attributes of vCenter
3. Get the attributes of VM’s in vCenter.

I am using Python 2.6.6.